# React hook form appending empty values for forms

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I have an object like this
`const formData = {interests:['footbal']}`

I need to construct forms based on this where user can add items on clicking the add button.

In the add button i have added empty value to the react hook form.

`fieldArray.append("")`

Here is the [stackblitz code link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-zfokzt)

The problem here is when i press the add button twice without adding anything in the inputs. its not updating the input array by appending the empty string items twice. rather its happening first time alone.

Answer (score 0):

I did not meet the problem you mentioned about but instead it appends the wrong way. You are just adding an object (`{value: ''}`) for all the different arrays you are using. You need to append the correct data, using the data format specific to format of the field array's elements.

For instance, you need to append `''` for `interests` and {
email: "",
phone: ""
} for `contactInfo`.